# Не работает php-fpm в режиме сокета на openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: php, linux, администрирование, php-fpm, opensuse

Все апдейты стоят.

```
zypper info php7-fpm 
Загрузка данных о репозиториях...
Чтение установленных пакетов...


Сведения — пакет php7-fpm:
--------------------------
Репозиторий            : Основной репозиторий (NON-OSS)
Имя                    : php7-fpm
Версия                 : 7.4.21-1.1
Архитектура            : x86_64
Поставщик              : openSUSE
Размер после установки : 8,1 MiB
Установлено            : Да
Состояние              : актуален
Пакет с исходным кодом : php7-fpm-7.4.21-1.1.src
Заключение             : Модуль PHP7 менеджера процессов FastCGI
Описание               : 
    PHP is a server-side, cross-platform HTML embedded scripting language.
    If you are completely new to PHP and want to get some idea of how it
    works, have a look at the Introductory tutorial. Once you get beyond
    that have a look at the example archive sites and some of the other
    resources available in the links section.
```

`/etc/php7/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Кусок `journald`:

```
Jul 10 02:36:25 opensuse-tumbleweed-test-01 php-fpm[7414]: [10-Jul-2021 02:36:25] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': Permission denied (13)
Jul 10 02:36:25 opensuse-tumbleweed-test-01 php-fpm[7414]: [10-Jul-2021 02:36:25] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jul 10 02:36:25 opensuse-tumbleweed-test-01 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
```

```
opensuse-leap-test-01:~ # ll /run/ | grep php
drwx--x--x  2 root   root     40 Jul  9 18:01 php-fpm
```

Самое отстойное, что тот же набор шагов (ставлю\настраиваю через ansible) на соседней виртуалке с `openSUSE Leap 15.3` делает всё как надо.

**UPD**: Если указать `ip:port` - сервис запускается и работает.

Comment: У вас сокет создаётся от имени `listen.owner = www-data` и `listen.group = www-data`, а права на папку `/run/php-fpm` `drwx--x--x  root   root`. Дайте права на запись либо пользователю `www-data`, либо группе `www-data`. Какой конфиг и какие права на папку "на соседней виртуалке"?

Comment: Конфиги одинаковые. `chmod 777 -R` не помогает. На `leap` права на папку - те же самые - и там всё ок.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uQPO6mJ

Comment: Удивительное дело! Боюсь, ничего более содержательного придумать не могу.

Comment: Может виноват SELinux?

Comment: `cat /etc/selinux/config` `SELINUX = disabled` :(